# Paypal payment done from which site

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have two websites and both sites have the same product to sale via PayPal payment. But now I required identifying that from which website a particular transaction made. I mean from which site this purchase made. 
So is there any way to identify this??

Many thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can specify different URL for handling IPN for different sites. As you know you can specify URL in your PayPal account, so if you use different accounts for different sites all will work well. If you use the same account, you can pass IPN handler URI as a parameter of api call, for example `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NOTIFYURL ` parameter in `SetExpressCheckout ` API call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'custom' variable where you can put an identifier in the button.So that when you receiving the payment, you can see the details from where it was come from. Here is the [link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) where you can have a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Inside each purchasing you must store into database a unique key token . Also you can use paypal transaction id for unique identifier. For recurring payments use for unique identificator subscr_id